# Getting HTML Contents of a File that has Spaces on its Directory Name

Tags: php, curl

Help,

I have a problem in getting the html contents of my file if its directory/folder name has spaces in it.

I am using CURL to grab the html contents.. Here is a sample of the link that i am accessing to grab the html codes

```
http://dev24oct20part2.globalbizcloud.com/admin/content/module_templates/templates/products/all_prods/Product temP/index.html
```

As you can see there is a space in the directory containing my index.html and this causes the error and disallows me from grabbing the contents.

```
/Product temP/index.html
```

Here's my code:

```
    $template = $this->mod_template_link.$this->module_category.'/'.$this->module_unique_key.'/'.$this->module_template.'/index.html';
    //value of this variable is the link above..

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $template);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $contents = curl_exec ($ch);
    curl_close ($ch);

    return $this->translate_template($contents);
```

If There are no spaces that exist in the folder name, it works fine.

Any advice or suggestions would be greatly appreciated..

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the error message? Show your code too.

Comment: the error that comes out is a HTTP Error 400 Bad request..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try filling up the space with `%20`

```
http://dev24oct20part2.globalbizcloud.com/admin/content/module_templates/templates/products/all_prods/Product%20temP/index.html
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to url-encode special characters, like space, for your case, replace spaces for `%20` , like so:

```
http://dev24oct20part2.globalbizcloud.com/admin/content/module_templates/templates/products/all_prods/Product%20temP/index.html
```

The proper solution is to pass the url through PHP [urlencode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) to have it escaped to use in cURL. So replace your following line:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $template);
```

for this one:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, urlencode($template) );
```

Comment: url_encoding $template did not work but replacing spaces with %20 made it work.. thanks for the help :)